# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined in React Native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I'm encountering an issue in my React Native application, where I'm getting the following error message:

This error is occurring in my React Native code, but I'm having trouble pinpointing the exact location of the problem. I would appreciate some guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

Here's a snippet of the code where the error is happening:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Easing, Value, timing } from 'react-native-reanimated';

function SliderPicker({ options }) {
    const [pickedOption, pickOption] = useState([]);
    const optionsRef = useRef({});
    const titlesRef = useRef({});
    const textColor = new Value(0);

    const handleOptionPick = (key) => {
        const optionPressed = optionsRef.current[key];
        const titlePressed = titlesRef.current[key];

        optionPressed.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
            pickOption([key, width, pageX]);
        });
    };

    const changeTextColor = () => {
        timing(textColor, {
            toValue: textColor.value === 0 ? 1 : 0,
            duration: 500,
            easing: Easing.linear,
        }).start();
    };

    const interpolateColor = textColor.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['black', 'red'], // You can change these colors as desired
    });

    return (
        <View className="flex-row items-center justify-between mt-2 mx-5 p-1.5 rounded-[14px] bg-midnightBlue">
            <View
                className="h-full absolute rounded-[10px] bg-majorelleBlue"
                style={{
                    left: pickedOption.length !== 0 ? pickedOption[2] - 20 : 0,
                    width: pickedOption.length !== 0 ? pickedOption[1] : 0,
                }}
            />
            {options.map((option) => (
                <View className="flex-1" key={option.key} ref={(ref) => (optionsRef.current[option.key] = ref)}>
                    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={() => handleOptionPick(option.key)}>
                        <Animated.Text
                            className={`py-0.5 text-center font-montsemi text-base text-white bg-transparent ${
                                pickedOption[0] === option.key ? `text-${interpolateColor}` : ''
                            }`}
                            ref={(ref) => (titlesRef.current[option.key] = ref)}
                            allowFontScaling={false}
                        >
                            {option.label}
                        </Animated.Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}

export default SliderPicker;
```

Any insights, suggestions, or explanations of what might be causing this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

btw I use nativewind

Comment: "I'm having trouble pinpointing the exact location of the problem" Then put logging in and find the exact line, once you've found the exact line you might discover what the error is yourself. I don't know what the problem is  but this is what you do when you have a problem but don't know where, you log and you debug and pinpoint. P.S. A javascript tag might be more useful in getting relevant eyes than an iOS and android tag